# finding thread index and block index in CUDA

Tags: cuda

The following code computes the sum of two vectors:

```
// Compute vector sum C = A+B
for (i = 0, i < 1000, i++)
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i]
```

The grid consists of 20 one-dimensional blocks and the block size (blockDim.x) is 50.

The iteration with i=400 will be assigned a thread. Can anyone help me with how to find threadIdx.x and blockIdx.x of this thread?

Comment: There is no unique answer. The code is serial, so every thread will perform that index

Comment: Each block has  50 threads.  Each thread would probably be assigned one result index from your for-loop.  The first block will handle indices 0..49.  The 2nd block will handle indices 50..99.  The 3rd block will handle indices 100..149.  Probably you can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella that was help full.

Comment: `if( i == 400 ) printf("i=400 => Thread %i Block %i\n", threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x);`

Comment: You may want to consider showing your kernel when asking about it rather than a serial loop.

Answer (score -2):

`threadIdx.x` and `blockIdx.x` inside your kernel will give you exactly that.

In your case you can calculate global index by:

```
int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```